# view all http request errors during/after jmeter load test

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I was wondering if there was a easier way to do this. Below is a simple load test specification:

[image]

WHen I run for high loads the **Summary Report** might report percentage errors. And you can also probably view those requests in that **View Results Tree** page. (That is if we catch the error-ed request quickly enough).

Now what do we do if we want to study all the errors to see if there is some pattern in them, or, simply to know all kinds of errors in the http load test? I am looking for some feature or hack to this effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which provides:

   - A Statistics table providing in one table a summary of all metrics per transaction including 3 configurable percentiles, basically the same as your Summary Report listener
   - An error table providing a summary of all errors and their proportion in the total requests
   - A Top 5 Errors by Sampler table providing for every Sampler (excluding Transaction Controller by default) the top 5 Errors
   - Response codes per second zoomable chart
2. There is a separate Listener - [Response Codes per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond)
3. JMeter [.jtl result files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) are basically .CSV files so you can open it with [MS Excel](https://office.live.com/start/excel.aspx) or equivalent and perform grouping or plot errors messages at a timeline chart
4. And last but not the least, for "high loads" it's recommended to disable or even remove all the Listeners (especially View Results Tree guy) because [they don't add any value and just consume the valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/).